# Notepad++:: Find lines that NOT in a particular format

Tags: php, regex, foreach, preg-match, preg-match-all

So I have a huge text file in that format :

```
$transation[123456]='Table9912333';
$transation[123457]='Table8123321';
$transation[123458]='Chair0123334';
```

Everything looks great but I want to find if there is a line that is NOT in that format inside that huge text file:

so IOW... This is the format of every line:

```
$transation[{ANY NUMBER}]='{ANY TEXT}';\r\n
```

I want to find an errors on that huge text line so basically if the line is NOT in the format above mark it...

Comment: Would a negative lookahead? `(?! ... )` not do the trick?

Comment: Is your question about finding the lines in `Notepad++` (as per the title) or in `PHP` (as per the numerous tags)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?!\$transation\[\d+\]='[^']*';$).*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qH1uG3/5

```
$re = "/^(?!\\$transation\\[\\d+\\]='[^']*';$).*$/m";
$str = "\$transation[123456]='Table9912333';\n\$transation[123457]='Table8123321';\n\$transation[123458]='Chair0123334';\n\$transation[123458]='Chair0123334'sdfds;";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

The `negative lookahead` will make sure the line matching is not in the required format.